# Difficulty with tabControl/tabitem refresh

Tags: c#, wpf, refresh, tabcontrol

I have a WPF window with a maintabWindow and several tabitems.
It normally works fine and the layout is this:

[image]

but when I BEFORE add the following window:

[image]

the result is this:

[image]

So the problem is related with the tabControl/tabItem refresh.
This is fairly obvious but even more because if I move the window or pass with the mouse on the a tabItem they get refreshed one by one.

I searched and found that here is a solution: http://geekswithblogs.net/NewThingsILearned/archive/2008/08/25/refresh--update-wpf-controls.aspx

so I added:

```
  this.MainTab.Refresh();
  this.tabItem1.Refresh();
  this.tabItem2.Refresh();
  this.tabItem3.Refresh();
  this.tabItem4.Refresh();
  this.tabItem5.Refresh();
```

but that didn't change a thing.

Thanx for any help

Comment: Can you, please, post some XAML?

Comment: You could try something like this:
http://xcalibursystems.com/tag/tab-control/

Comment: @Xcalibur37 alas not working.  BUT the other solution that you proposed as potentially not working.... works. So In any case thanx for your help!!!! You might propose it as a solution if you want.

Comment: Been blocked while editing comment. This one works fine.... 
for (var i = 0; i < myTabControl.Items.Count; i++)
{
    myTabControl.SelectedIndex = i;
    myTabControl.UpdateLayout();
}

Comment: I had a similiar problem. `mainTab.Update()` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so in the end it has a quite a weird behavious. If I do

```
for (int i = 0; i < tbcMain.Items.Count; i++)
  {
    tbcMain.SelectedIndex = i;
    tbcMain.UpdateLayout();
  }
```

it works. But I have to set the 1st tabitem so if I add

```
 tbcMain.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

it doesn't.
So the solution was put a sleep and it works again.

```
for (int i = 0; i < tbcMain.Items.Count; i++)
  {
    tbcMain.SelectedIndex = i;
    tbcMain.UpdateLayout();
  }

  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
  tbcMain.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

But that is not elegant at all. If anyone has a better solution pls let me know it.
Btw adding the tbcMain.SelectedIndex = 0; on the loaded event of the mainWindow is of no use.

Comment: Don't add `tbcMain.SelectedIndex = i;` in your loop.  It's not needed.  You can just do `tabItem1.UpdateLayout()`, `tabItem2.UpdateLayout()`, etc. directly.  If you want to do a loop, just append `i` to the TabItem name.  Then you set your `.SelectedIndex = 0` at the end, like you did, or set it first.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set your SelectedIndex first, and without having to include it in your loop:

```
tbcMain.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Then, basing it off of your response, you should be able to either just do `.UpdateLayout()` on each of your TabItems:

```
MainTab.UpdateLayout();
tabItem1.UpdateLayout();
tabItem2.UpdateLayout();
tabItem3.UpdateLayout();
tabItem4.UpdateLayout();
tabItem5.UpdateLayout();
```

Or you should be able to do something like this in your loop:

```
MainTab.UpdateLayout();
for (int i = 0; i < tbcMain.Items.Count; i++)
{
    TabItem tbi = (TabItem)this.FindControl("tabItem"+i);
    tbi.UpdateLayout();
}
```

Updating/refreshing should have nothing to do with setting the selected one.  Including the selection of the tab within the loop to `i` was your problem - not a [race condition](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davidklinems/2005/10/24/what-is-a-race-condition/).  Set the `tbcMain.SelectedIndex = 0` outside of your loop and you should be fine.  Sometimes, however, this doesn't work and you need to set it with `Dispatcher`:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => this.tbcMain.SelectedIndex = 0));
```

There's a write up/comments on a separate thread regarding why it needs to be sent to `Dispatcher`:

[How to programmatically select a TabItem in WPF TabControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929646/how-to-programmaticaly-select-a-tabitem-in-wpf-tabcontrol)

Though, unfortunately for me, I had a similar issue where I was trying to refresh a ListView on a subtab.  Neither `.UpdateLayout()`, nor `.InvalidateVisual()` (as I saw on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22877919/refresh-reload-mui-wpf-page-when-tab-is-changed)) worked.  I just had to rebind my grid in the button event I was using on my main page, so that when the tab was clicked, it was refreshed manually.  I added an `x:Name` property on the tab so I could call it using "dot" syntax, and it exposed the ListView.  I simply added the DataTable of results back to that ListView's DataContext.